# how to set Select Pixels as HotKey

Tags: adobe-photoshop

How to set Select Pixels of the layer at the right panel in Photoshop or may be there is another such a function to get selected all pixels of the active object

[image]

I've read every hotkey in Edit-> Keybord Shortcuts, but no such function has been in there.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Ctrl/Command</kbd> + `click` on the thumbnail in the **Layers Panel** should do it

Comment: no, that doesnt select all pixels of active object

Comment: @AlexNikonov Yes it does... always has. You may not **see** "marching ants" around pixels which are less than 50% opaque, but it selects all non-transparent areas, i.e. pixels.

Comment: If you are seeking to select all areas as 100%, regardless of pixel transparency, then that's another matter entirely.